# Installing Pygame through Pycharm or System Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

Im currently running Python 3.7.0b4 and attempting to install the Pygame package, however I keep getting the error.

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pygame\

This is the error produced by the system terminal, another distinct error by Pycharm is:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

This is for installing Pygame 1.9.3.

My pip is up to date and so is my set-up tools. I have no idea how to progress at this point.

Full system terminal error output.

> Collecting Pygame
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/06/3c25051549c252cc6fde01c8aeae90b96831370884504fe428a623316def/pygame-1.9.3.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>
> WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
>   Using WINDOWS configuration...
>
> Path for SDL not found.
>       Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
>       Path for FONT not found.
>       Path for IMAGE not found.
>       Path for MIXER not found.
>       Path for PNG not found.
>       Path for JPEG not found.
>       Path for PORTMIDI not found.
>       Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
>       Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
>       Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
>       Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.
>
> If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
>       the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.
>
> Continuing With "setup.py"
>       Error with the "Setup" file,
>       perhaps make a clean copy from "Setup.in".
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pygame\setup.py", line 165, in 
>           extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')
>         File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\extension.py", line 171, in read_setup_file
>           line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)
>         File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 407, in expand_makefile_vars
>           s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]
>       TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
>
> ---
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pygame\

Comment: Please show more error output. I also presume than running 3.7 beta could be an issue, I suggest you use 3.6.

Comment: Ive added the full output, the initial error i posted was only what showed up as red.

Comment: You don't have the SDL installed. This is a requirement for pygame. I presume for less cutting edge python versions there might be wheels available including the SDL, but here you need to invest a bit more time. You will also need visual studio, do you have that installed?

Comment: Here you find the available wheels: https://pypi.org/project/Pygame/#files - no python 3.7 yet. I would strongly suggest to move to python 3.6.

Comment: I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 installed. What is the SDL that I would have to install?

Comment: Ahh ok Ive seen that rolling back to version 3.6 would be a solution, but i wasnt sure if it was necessary. Ill see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame docs recommends that you use *Python version 3.6.1* or greater, so I would suggest you to use the most recent non-beta version. Also, some pygame wheels are not available to this version yet.

After the python installation make sure its added to your **PATH** variable and try to install Pygame using this command given that you are on windows:

```
py -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

If you get a **PermissionError** then run the command prompt as administrator.

Comment: After re-installing python 3.6.1 I no longer got an error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The same way you are installing pygame, you have to do it for pip first to get rid of the error. Once you install the new version of pip, pygame should install just fine.

Comment: Could you replace "The same way as ..." with code examples?