# cant install pygame in pycharm

Tags: pygame, pycharm, installation

First of all, I'm new to programming. So,forgive me for my mistakes. I've installed pygame in python IDLE. But when I try to install it in pycharm, this happens:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
(venv) C:\Users\ARMAN\PycharmProjects\GAMES>pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...

Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x86"?[Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ARMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5f1r3j6w\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\ARMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5f1r3j6w\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\ARMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5f1r3j6w\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\ARMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5f1r3j6w\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ARMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5f1r3j6w\pygame\

(venv) C:\Users\ARMAN\PycharmProjects\GAMES>py -m pip install -U pygame --user
Collecting pygame
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x86"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ARMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nykuwxyw\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\ARMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nykuwxyw\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\ARMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nykuwxyw\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\ARMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nykuwxyw\pygame\buildconfig\downloa
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ARMAN\AppData\Local\T
(venv) C:\Users\ARMAN\PycharmProjects\GAMES>
```

I get an error. I've updated everything. Found a similar problem here:
     https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000435070-Command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1-whatever-package-I-try-to-install-. 
But I can't understand the solution. So, please kindly help me.

Comment: Have you downloaded Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my answer, but an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392215/installing-pygame-through-pycharm-or-system-terminal?rq=1):

> Pygame docs recommends that you use Python version 3.6.1 or greater,
>   so I would suggest you to use the most recent non-beta version. Also,
>   some pygame wheels are not available to this version yet.
>
> After the python installation make sure its added to your PATH
>   variable and try to install Pygame using this command given that you
>   are on windows:
>
> ```
> py -m pip install -U pygame --user
> ```
>
> If you get a PermissionError then
>   run the command prompt as administrator.

I hope this helps.